# Vinyl grooves look like scratch

Tags: vinyl

I got here a few records which looked if they are scratched.
The scratches (if they are scratches) look like grooves. (They lay exact in the same direction as the grooves)
But if I listen to this records, you hear nothing, just music. No cracks or jumps or something in between, only music.

I tried to make two pictures, where you can slightly see the scratches.

Can someone tell me what this is. Are these light scratches or do they only look like scratches.

Regards
LStrike[image: vinyl scratch one][image: vinyl scratch 2]

Comment: You're not just talking about the gaps between the tracks, where it's darker, are you?

Comment: No, I am not talking about the gaps.

Comment: OK sorry just checking as that's where the red was! actually I do see what you mean now...

Comment: No problem, maybe a little bit complicated to explain my issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's hard to tell from the photos, but there are two possibilities I can think of…

1. Random chance of frequencies
   Sometimes frequencies in the recording do just seem to highlight better than others. If there is a particularly board-spectrum sound at that point, white noise or something high & 'fizzy' there's a chance that could do it.
   Also, possibly very quiet or even silent passages may produce a highly reflective surface.
2. Damage to the top of the groove but not its entire depth
   An extremely blunt or cracked/split stylus can damage the very top of the 'valley' of the groove; or something got jammed around the stylus at that point, but then moved away or was left behind; or at one time extra pressure was applied just at that point on a shallow-point stylus; or if it was a frequently-used cue-drop-point…. or something was spilled, a tiny droplet that the stylus took with it & spread for a few seconds, subsequent passes would clean out the stylus-path but not the top of the groove.
   In all these, if only the top of the groove was affected, a good, clean stylus wouldn't 'see' it on the way past, so it would still sound fine.

Comment: If it runs around the entire circumference of the record (as it appears to do), Tetsujin is likely correct.  I've seen that happen in quieter passages of a song as well where there is less instrumentation, which aligns with reason #1 above.

Comment: ah, ty @JohnnyBones - I hadn't thought of quiet or even silent passages, as a particularly reflective surface. Will tweak answer

Comment: Re point 2 - I used to buy, as a poor, starving student, ex-jukebox records - some of them had almost white surfaces with the amount of blunt needle damage they'd had, but a good stylus would simply 'see' below where the worn styli ever reached & they didn't sound too bad.

Comment: To add further weight to #1, a [groove on a record](https://wharferj.files.wordpress.com/2011/03/magnified-grooves.jpg) is shaped **exactly** like a wave form in the digital domain.  So, music that needs a wider wave form is going to have grooves spread out further to accomodate them in a concentric circle.  Music with a more condensed wave form (like quiet music) can have those grooves closer together, which will make them look shiny.

Comment: Your answer sounds good. Maybe it is light damage on the grooves. The next time I will listen more closely to the record to check if in that area are high frequencies or maybe some light cracks. Thanks so far.

Comment: I am not sure what I am facing here. I think these scratches are scratches, but only some light ones on the surface. Must been a problem with the turntable of the previous owner of the records. I got three records with those scratches and they are all at the same position. Thank you all.